# datetimepicker - use a time that is rounded to nearest 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am using a bootstrap datetimepicker. I want to have the time rounded up to the nearest 5 minutes.

I tried:

```
var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
var date = new Date(); //or use any other date
var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);
console.log('rounded = ' + rounded)
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#meetingTime').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: rounded,
            format: 'HH:mm'
        });
        $('#meetingTime').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: rounded,
            format: 'HH:mm'
        })
    }
);
```

In the console I see that rounded up date object is created. However in the datetimepicker the rounded up date is not used and the current date is used.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which specific datepicker library are you using? Good ones will have a configurable option for you to set the minute interval between options.

Comment: https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus version : 4.15.35

Comment: Would you like to change the time to 5min increments after user picks it or you want the options to be limited to 5min increments? I guess the latter makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version:

```js
var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
var date = new Date(); //or use any other date
var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);
console.log('rounded = ' + rounded);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#meetingTime').datetimepicker({
    date: rounded,
    format: 'HH:mm',
    stepping: 5 // optional: sets the increment of the minutes to 5
  });
});
```

Update:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#meetingTime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH:mm',
    stepping: 5 // optional: sets the increment of the minutes to 5
  }).on('focusin', function() {
    var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
    var date = new Date(); //or use any other date
    var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);
    $(this).data('DateTimePicker').date(rounded);
  });
});
```

Comment: this sets the date already for the field, is it possible to set the value when the datepicker field is actually entered?

Comment: try to add an 'focusin' event listener to the datetimepicker field. In focusin event add this:

var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
    var date = new Date(); //or use any other date
    var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);
    $(this).data('DateTimePicker').date(rounded);

Comment: really great. tnx for the help!